# How to show a fullScreenCover on top of a sheet in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

MRE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present sheet") {
            showingSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            SheetView(showingSheet: $showingSheet)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State private var showFullScreen = false
    @Binding var showingSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press to fullscreen") {
            showingSheet = false
            showFullScreen = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullScreen,
                         onDismiss: didDismiss) {
            VStack {
                Text("A full-screen modal view.")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Tap to Dismiss")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                showFullScreen.toggle()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                   maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
        }
    }
    func didDismiss() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
    }
}

struct FullScreen: View {
    @Binding var isShowSheet: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            .onTapGesture {
                isShowSheet = false
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

when the full screen cover is shown, it is immediately dismissed along with the sheet.

I need want to either:

1. Dismiss the sheet, and show the full screen cover
2. Leave the sheet there, show the full screen cover but when the full screen is dismissed the sheet should be gone already. Not two slide down animations which is the default.

Comment: To complete the answer : you attached the full screen to the sheet, so when dismissing sheet you also dismiss any of the views it would have displayed. This is a logic problem. To have full screen stay it must be linked to the ContentView .

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using two different presentation? However you can achieve that with single presentation as well as I did in below code. The way you are doing will not work well. As the dismissal of presentation follows in hierarchy. What you are doing is dismissing the first and at the same time you want to present an other on that one which ultimately has to fail.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present sheet") {
            showingSheet.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            SheetView(showingSheet: $showingSheet)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State private var showFullScreen = false
    @Binding var showingSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Press to fullscreen") {
                    showFullScreen = true
                }
            }

            if showFullScreen {
                VStack {
                    Text("A full-screen modal view.")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Tap to Dismiss")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                       maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .onTapGesture {
                    showFullScreen = false
                    showingSheet = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly review the above code and let me know whether it solves your problem and achieve the functionality you want. For any confusion feel free to ask. Thanks